# Rails 4 adding stylesheet

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, stylesheet

I have searched for an answer on this website but nothing so far. I am on a learning curve: learning while creating my own rails app.

in my app/assets/stylesheets I have some stylesheets. In the public folder I have my index.html page

I am trying to add some stylesheets but nothing is working. I have added this: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %> inside the`application.html.erd file. I assume that's where the stylesheet should be included but still nothing. I go ahead and place the `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %> inside the index.html page but it only shows entire code as text in the browser. Am I doing something wrong?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.html is a html page,it cannot render rails commands,either change the file name to index.html.erb and then include <%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %> or use the link tag of html to load your css in index.html.